# odoo many2one field filter by domain

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want to filter `name_id` field by domain. Was trying:

name_id = fields.Many2one('my.model.line', string='Product', domain=[('purchase_request_id', '=', model_id)])

but then I got an error:

```
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    return self._attrs[name]
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    return self._attrs[name]
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    return self._attrs[name]
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    return self._attrs[name]
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    return self._attrs[name]
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

my_model.xml

```
 <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_my_model_form">
     <field name="name">my.model.form</field>
     <field name="model">my.model</field>
     <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="My Model">
          <header>
               <field name="my_model_line">
                     <tree>
                         field name="name"/>
                      </tree>
               </field>
      <notebook>
           <page>
              <field name="supply_conditions_status">
                  <tree string="My model Lines">
                        <field name="name_id"/>
                  </tree>
```

Models:

```
class SupplyConditions(models.Model):
    _name = 'supply.conditions'
    name_id = fields.Many2one('my.model.line', string='Product')
    model_id = fields.Many2one('my.model')

class MyModelLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.model.line'
    name = fields.Char('Name')
    my_model_id = fields.Many2one('my.model')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.model'
    title = fields.Char('Title')
    my_model_line = fields.One2many('my.model.line', 'my_model_id')
    supply_conditions_status = fields.One2many('supply.conditions', 'model_id')
```

**UPDATE:**

I mean:
domain=[('my_model_id', '=', model_id)])

Answer (score 0):

you are applying a domain having purchase_request_id as a field, but there's no field name purchase_request_id in model 'my.model.line'. Try this code:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.model'
    title = fields.Char('Title')
    my_model_line = fields.One2many('my.model.line', 'my_model_id')
    supply_conditions_status = fields.One2many('supply.conditions', 'model_id')

class MyModelLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.model.line'
    name = fields.Char('Name')
    my_model_id = fields.Many2one('my.model', ondelete='cascade')
    purchase_request_id = fields.Many2one('your_purchase_request_model')

class SupplyConditions(models.Model):
    _name = 'supply.conditions'
    name_id = fields.Many2one('my.model.line', string='Product', domain=[('purchase_request_id', '=', model_id)])
    model_id = fields.Many2one('my.model')
```

Hope this will solve your problem. Have a nice day.